# How can i access json elements which is in string Array.(C#)

Tags: c#-4.0

How can i access json elements which is in string Array.(C#)

```
[
{"Hello"},
{"World"},
{"!!!!"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
 var obj = $.parseJSON('["Hello","World","!!!!"]');
        alert(obj[0]);
        alert(obj[1]);
        alert(obj[2]);
```